# Unexpected TikZ coding change inside a pic

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to draw many TikZ pictures that contain subdiagrams like:

[image]

Modulo the styling, which is below, I can do this using the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[vertex](1) at (1,0){};
  \node[vertex](2) at (2,0){};
  \draw(1) to[out=60, in=120]node[colour]{$1$}(2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I need to draw quite a lot of these so I decided to streamline it by defining a pic:

```
\tikzset{
  pics/cap/.style = {
    code = {
      \foreach \x [count=\c from 0, remember=\x as \y] in {#1} {
         \node[vertex](\x) at (\x,0){};
         \ifnum\c>0
             \draw(\y) to [out=60, in=120] node[colour]{$\c$} (\x);
         \fi
      }
    }
  },
}
```

so that I can write the example above as:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic at (0,0) {cap={1,2}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work and instead produces:

[image]

Is anyone able to explain to me why my `pics` code does not give the same output as the "hands-on" approach?

Here is the full code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  colour/.style = {
    circle,
    draw,
    fill=white,
    font=\small,
    inner sep=0.2pt,
  },
  pics/cap/.style = {
    code = {
      \foreach \x [count=\c from 0, remember=\x as \y] in {#1} {
         \node[vertex](\x) at (\x,0){};
         \ifnum\c>0
             \draw(\y) to [out=60, in=120] node[colour]{$\c$} (\x);
         \fi
      }
    }
  },
  vertex/.style = {
    circle,
    radius=1mm,
    inner sep=-2.0pt,
    fill=black
  },
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[vertex](1) at (1,0){};
      \node[vertex](2) at (2,0){};
      \draw(1) to[out=60, in=120]node[colour]{$1$}(2);
    \end{tikzpicture}

  \bigskip

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic at (0,0) {cap={1,2}};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you corrected your `\pic` code now. Just add the `midway` option to the `colour` node.

Comment: So I take it that the question is really why you need to add `midway` to place the node while inside the `\pic`, but not outside?

Comment: @JasperHabicht Yes: why do the defaults change? Is there a good reason or is this a bug?

Comment: A pic is parsed like a node. This process will set the `pos` value to empty if the node/pic is not placed along a path. (Yes, you could do `(0,0) -- pic[sloped] {cap={1,2}} (1,2)`.) However, the whole pic code will inherit that then. You could do `every pic/.append style=midway` if you want a more general solution for that or add `midway` for that specific node. Or should the position of your colour node change depending on the setting of the `pos`ition outside of the pic?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks for the explanation. I'd be happy to accept that as the answer -- or, if you don't want to do this, to mark Juan Castaño's as correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A pic is a node … not really, of course, but TikZ uses the same mechanism that parses a node specification for the pic parsing just with a flag raised (`\iftikz@node@is@pic`)
and indeed, it is possible to place pics along a path, say

```
\draw (0,0) -- pic[sloped] {cap = {3, 5}} (1,2);
```

(Here, we would run into the first conflict if the pic was placed explicitly not by the default `midway` (`pos = 0.5`). Should the nodes inside the pic then placed `midway`, the default position of the scope outside of the pic or the same way the pic itself was placed?)

Now, one of the first things a `node` (and thus a `pic`) does is to check another flag: `\iftikz@node@is@a@label`.
The name is misleading because it's not about a TikZ label but whether a node (or pic) has been found between a path operation (`--`, `to[…]`, etc.) and its target coordinate.

If it wasn't than the value for `pos` is emptied out which signals that no timer should be applied. (Timer are the algorithms that place a node along a path segment.)

---

All these things make sure that a default `pos`ition can be given without nodes that are placed behind the target coordinate of a path segment are using a previous set timer.

We want to differentiate between

```
\path (c1) -- node {X} (c2);
```

which would place the node along the straight line (according to whatever `pos` is currently set)
and

```
\path (c1) -- (c2) node {X};
```

which would place the node at `c2`
but also allow

```
\path (c1) -- (c2) node[midway] {X};
```

to place the node on the line segment even if it was specified after it. (In the last case, TikZ is just missing an interface to toggle the node to be a “label” without having to give an explicit `pos`ition.)

---

For a `pic` the same rules should apply, I guess, we want all these three cases to work the same as with a node:

```
\path (c1) --      pic         {X} (c2);
\path (c1) -- (c2) pic         {X};
\path (c1) -- (c2) pic[midway] {X};
```

TikZ just has no proper scoping for the `pos`ition built in and all nodes (and pics) are always treated to not be along a path segment. I'd consider the fact that this happens a bug but it's not really severe.

---

Where do *you* want the nodes to be? At the middle of the arc? Then set `midway` explicitly as [Juan Castaño](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/688469) has shown.
Do you want them placed like the pic has been placed? Like the setting outside of the pic?

If you don't use your pic along a path and/or with a name (`pic (picname) {cap = …}`) then it's just a fancy shortcut which you don't need a `pic` for. A simple macro or some other PGFKeys approach could be taken.

Here's such a solution. This uses the on path key `make colour chain` and uses the `chains` library to place *n* nodes given a list of *n* − 1 “labels”.

The first node is placed whereever the current position of the path is, all others are placed 1 in the *xyz* coordinate system to the right, the same as you did manually. The `join` option is used to draw the edges between the vertices, it's smart enough to not try to connect the first node with a non-existing predecessor.

Though, I've opted for defaulting `colour` to `midway`. A user can always change the `colour` style to use another `pos`ition:

```
\tikzset{colour/.append style={pos=.12345}}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\tikzset{
  colour/.style={% yes, explicitly midway
    circle, draw, fill=white, font=\small, inner sep=.2pt, midway},
  vertex/.style={
    circle, draw, fill, inner sep=2pt},
  colour join/.style={bend left=60, edge node={node[colour]{#1}}},
  make colour chain/.style={
    start chain=colour chain going {at={([shift=(right:1)]\tikzchainprevious.center)}},
    insert path={
      node foreach \x in {,#1} [vertex, on chain=colour chain, join=by {colour join={\x}}] {}
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\tikz\draw[make colour chain={1, 5, 43}];
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (5,3); \draw[help lines, ->] (0,0) -- (30:.8);
\path[rotate=30, ->, blue] (1,0) [make colour chain={5, 4, 11}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for adding the chains example, which I've not seen before:). I don't think that they work in my real use-case as the distance between nodes is not constant, and nor is the height of the arcs (none of these details are relevant to my question, which is only a MWE:).

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for something like this:
[image]

I changed your `\pic` code and added the option `midway` to the `colour` style.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618]{standalone}

\tikzset{
  colour/.style = {
    circle,
    draw,
    fill=white,
    font=\small,
    inner sep=0.2pt,
    midway% <-- added
  },
  pics/cap/.style = {
    code = {
      \node[vertex](0) at (0,0){};
      \foreach \x in {#1} {
         \pgfmathtruncatemacro\y{\x-1}
         \node[vertex](\x) at (\x,0){};
         \draw(\y) to [out=60, in=120] node[colour]{$\x$} (\x);
      }
    }
  },
  vertex/.style = {
    circle,
    radius=1mm,
    inner sep=-2.0pt,
    fill=black
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic at (0, 0) {cap={1,2}};
  \pic at (0,-1) {cap={1,...,5}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. That will fix the problem but it still does not answer my question that, in view of your answer, could be rephrased as asking why the default positioning changes from `pos=0.5` to `pos=1` inside a pic. (Btw, the nodes do not need to be consecutive, so using `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` will not work in my real use-case, which is also why I need the `count=\c`.)